# How do I know what OkHttp call I am returning from

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I have an activity that implements okhttp3.Callback and overrides the onFailure and onResume methods.
There are multiple different requests called in this activity, something similar to this:

```
Request request1 = RequestBuilder.login(username,password);
okHttpClient.newCall(request1).enqueue(this);
Request request2 = RequestBuilder.getData(token);
okHttpClient.newCall(request2).enqueue(this);
```

How can I know if I am returning from request1 or request2 in the onResponse method, since the response needs to be handled differently for each request?

Comment: What about `Callback` for `enqueue()` method? Did you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: in `onResponse(Response response)` use `response.request()` to get the `RequestObject` and compare that with yours.

Option 2: instead of `this`, use a anonymous class, like so:

```
okHttpClient.newCall(request1).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, Throwable throwable) {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                ...
            }
        });
```

and again for the second request:

```
okHttpClient.newCall(request2).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, Throwable throwable) {
                    ...
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    ...
                }
            });
```